# python script to execute git command and display output on a html page

Tags: python, git, bash

I'm a newbie to python and git. Im trying to write a python script to execute the git commands and diplay the output on a html page when a button is clicked on the html page. I'm trying to make use of  subprocess.Popen. But it displays nothing. Please help me out!!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.5
import cgi
import subprocess
import os
print "Content-type: text/html\n"
print
print """\
<html>
<head>
<title> Initialization of Repository </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2><pre>              Initialization of Git Repo </pre></h2>
"""
pr=subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/git','init'],
    cwd=os.path.dirname('/home/manju/Desktop/manju/'),
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=False)
(out,error)=pr.communicate()
print """\
print '%s\n'
""" % out

pr=subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/git','status'],
    cwd=os.path.dirname('/home/manju/Desktop/manju/'),
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=False)
(out1,error)=pr.communicate()
 print """\
print '%s\n'
<h3> Git Repository successfully Initialized </h3>
</body>
</html>   
""" % out1
```

Comment: You need to use `\r\n` for headers, not `\n` (it's not your problem, just a comment). Example: `print 'Content-type: text/html\r\n',` (you need the trailing `,` to prevent `print` from adding a `\n`)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker i tired it but still there is no change. There's something wrong in the subprocess.Popen. It doesnt display anything after executing the first statement.. The same script works excellent on if displayed on console without the html tags

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in having a look at [GitPython](http://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.1/tutorial.html). Install it via:

```
$ sudo pip install GitPython
```

And then replace your code with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.5

import os
import os.path

from git import *

REPO_DIR = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'repository')
repo = Repo.init(REPO_DIR)
status = repo.git.status()

print """\
Content-type: text/html


<html>
<head>
<title> Initialization of Repository </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2><pre>              Initialization of Git Repo </pre></h2>
Initialized empty Git repository at %s
print '%s\n'
<h3> Git Repository successfully Initialized </h3>
</body>
</html>
""" % (REPO_DIR, status)
```

As a side note: you may be interested in template engines such as [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org) to get HTML and Python disentangled :)

Comment: As a side note to logc's side note, OP, Python's `%` operator for String formatting will [gladly take a tuple or dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), so for this simple case you can even disentangle it without using any other template engine.

Comment: You are right, @JeffBowman. I have edited my answer to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: @logc i've already installed GitPython. Even with the replacement its blank. i changed 'repository' from ur code to '/home/manju/Desktop/manju/' which is the path to my repository. But its not working. Im think of trying out the template engines.

Comment: Hey @Tyson, notice that I put an `os.getcwd()` in front of the REPO_DIR path. That means the repository is created as a subdirectory of the current working directory (that is, from where you are executing the script). Check to see if there is a new directory there. Otherwise, if you will always create the repo at the same place, just put that as the value of REPO_DIR.